# Office add-ins (JS) not showing in Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I had been scouring documentation to check how we can enable/show/display office add-ins in Outlook 2013. The button Get-Addins does not show in my Outlook 2013-32bit either. Here is a screenshot :

[image]

I tried enabling "connected experience" but I could not find the setting in Office 2013. Is there a  configuration or registry key I need to set to be able to show my office add-ins in Outlook 2013?

Please note that these add-ins are successfully shown in the browser, in Office 2016 and 2019.

Thank you very much for any assistance you can extend to me.

Here is the version of Outlook 2013 (32-bit) I am working on :

[image]

Again, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some application specific APIs only became available with Office 2016, per
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview

However different aspects seems to be partially supported for Office 2013, per
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/office-add-in-requirement-sets

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins also seems to say 2013 is supported. So it depends on the exact API/functionality you are desiring...

Comment: Hello @vash thank you for your answers. The issue though is not just my addin. Even the "get addins" button is missing.  Pretty much like this issue :  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_security-mso_o365b/get-add-ins-button-is-missing-from-my-outlook-365/16569cdd-69a1-4601-bd00-b35a1912ee96